# JavaScript - run function on <input> change - NO JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to run a function when a HTML `<input/>` tag changes. How do I do this? There are some answers for this but they are all in jQuery and I want plain javascript. Can someone give me a simple example? Thanks!

I want the input to be a type as text:

```
<input type="text" id="change">
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event. This will trigger not only on key up and paste, but also other text modification events such as drag & drop.

```js
change.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="change">
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
    console.log(this.value);
}, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/y9xcoqja/

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

> The `EventTarget.addEventListener()` method registers the specified listener on the `EventTarget` it's called on. The event target may be an Element in a `document`, the `Document` itself, a `Window`, or any other object that supports events (such as `XMLHttpRequest`).

**EDIT**

To bind multiple events on the same element:

```
var element = document.getElementById('change');

function myEventHandler(event) {

}


element.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
    myEventHandler(evt);
}, false);

element.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    myEventHandler(evt);
}, false);
```

Comment: I'd also add mouseup event, or cut&paste events wouldn't be intercepted

Comment: @AndreaLigios how do I add a second event?

Comment: Thanks Tushar but the Answer from RGraham makes your 2 eventListeners, 1 eventListener using the input event

Comment: @Finiox I've just added those two event listeners to show how multiple events can be added on a single element. You should use the `keyup` event as shown above