# How to use a number from HTML number input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers

I'm trying to create a countdown timer using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and for that purpose I'm having the user input three integers for the number of hours, minutes, and seconds. I'm using the HTML input type "number" to do so, and I want to use this number inputed by the user in the JavaScript code that creates the countdown timer.

HTML input code:

```
<input type = "number" id = "hour" value = "0" min = "0" max = "59"/>
<input type = "number" id = "min" value = "0" min = "0" max = "59"/>
<input type = "number" id = "sec" value = "0" min = "0" max = "59"/>
```

Javascript code to use the numbers from the input as an integer.

```
let hour = parseInt(document.getElementById("hour").value,10); 
let min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value,10); 
let sec = parseInt(document.getElementById("sec").value, 10);
```

When I physically set hour, min, and sec within the javascript code, the code works without any issues, showing me that the problem is not in my code for the timer, but rather either the code that gets the user input in HTML or in the code that sets it as a variable in JavaScript. However, when I set it to be the input from the user, the code does not work. It would be great if I could get some pointers as to what I can change for the code to work. Thanks!

Comment: Consider [`document.getElementById("hour").valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) etc.

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) The three input values are retrieved correctly. When and how do you retrieve them? What doesn’t work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], preferably in the form of a stack snippet.

Comment: See [How to create Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212).

Comment: Are you using an input event?
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/30807034/2512571](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30807034/2512571)

Comment: Are you using an input event?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30807034/2512571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript understand your code, it also understands the you want it to get the user input of your form fields into variables, the thing JS is confused about is 'WHEN' do you want it to carry out this tasks? What 'EVENT' should trigger it to act according to your instructions? Here's an example:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type = "number" id = "hour" value = "0" min = "0" max = "59"/>
    <input type = "number" id = "min" value = "0" min = "0" max = "59"/>
    <input type = "number" id = "sec" value = "0" min = "0" max = "59"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("change", myfunc);
        function myfunc(){
        let hour = parseInt(document.getElementById("hour").value,10); 
        let min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value,10); 
        let sec = parseInt(document.getElementById("sec").value, 10);
        console.log(hour);
        console.log(min);
        console.log(sec);
    }
        
 </script>
```

I've added a form tag to your code, all i'm doing here is to get JS to watch for 'CHANGES'
to the form. Immediately JS notices any change in the form content, it runs the function 'myfunc()'.
You may read more about JS Events Here