# blocking field input from a non-=integer value - JS

Tags: javascript, forms, input

i am quite new to JavaScript.
I am trying to make it so that if anything other than a number is entered it either blocks it or it takes their entry and tells them to enter a number (because their entry is not acceptable) - I don't know which is easier.

The code I have so far:

```js
const calculateEntered = document.querySelector(".js- 
    calculateButton ")

    const calculateTotal = () => {

      let enteredValue = document.querySelector(".js-enterValue").value


      if (enteredValue < 40) {
        console.log(`<40>`)
        enteredValue = parseFloat(enteredValue) + 10
        document.querySelector(".js-totalText").innerHTML = `Your 
    total is: £${enteredValue}`
      } else if (enteredValue => 40 && enteredValue != NaN) {


        document.querySelector(".js-totalText").innerHTML = `Your total 
    is: £${enteredValue}`
      }
    }
```

```html
<button class="js-calculateButton">Calculate total</button>
<div>
  <div>
    <p class="js - enterTotalHere">Enter order total here: £</p>
  </div>
  <div><input placeholder="cost of order" class="js- 
    enterValue"></input>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="js-totalText"> Your total is: </p>
```

Any characters added lead to the "else if" statement. I tried looking this up but the solutions seemed very difficult - I didn't want to use any 3rd party method.

Comment: Why not use `type="number"`?

Comment: If you use an `input` element, you can set it to `type="number"` and the browser will display a message if the value that's entered is not a number.

Comment: Also, why are there spaces here?  `class="js - enterTotalHere"`

Comment: `</input>` closing tag doesn't exist. Your code is invalid

Comment: Specically, to your case `type="number"` can be used with `min="0"` to set a minimum value, zero here as it is a cost, it won't be negative

Comment: Also, if you use JS for numeric operations / evaluations, remember that the value of an input is of type string.  So you will need to parse the value to a proper data type such as integer or float.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321040/how-to-use-a-number-from-html-number-input-in-javascript) is an example

Comment: `<input type="number" min="yourMin" max="yourMax">`

Comment: but when I enter type="number" two arrows appear into the input field allowing them to add/minus numbers, anyway to stop that from appearing?

Also, 

If </input> doesn't exist, this is correct?:
<div><p class="js-enterTotalHere">Enter order total here: £</p></div><div><input type="number" placeholder = "cost of order" class = "js-enterValue"></div>

Comment: You can have either `<input [attributes]>` or `<input [attributes] />` depending on if you want to be XHTML-compatible (the second one). Happily for you HTML is designed as an error-less system for backwards compatibility, all that is invalid will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the input event on the input element and then calculate the result.

```js
document.forms.form01.cost.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let costNum = Number(e.target.value);
  form.result.value = (costNum < 40) ? costNum + 10 : costNum;
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <button class="js-calculateButton">Calculate total</button>
  <p class="js - enterTotalHere">Enter order total here: £</p>
  <div>
    <input name="cost" type="number" placeholder="cost of order" class="js-enterValue">
  </div>
  <p class="js-totalText"> Your total is: £<output name="result"></output></p>
</form>
```

If you don't like the arrows on the input element (`type="number"`) an alternative could be to use `type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="\d*"`:

```js
document.forms.form01.cost.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let costNum = Number(e.target.value);
  form.result.value = (costNum < 40) ? costNum + 10 : costNum;
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <button class="js-calculateButton">Calculate total</button>
  <p class="js - enterTotalHere">Enter order total here: £</p>
  <div>
    <input name="cost" type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="\d*" placeholder="cost of order" class="js-enterValue">
  </div>
  <p class="js-totalText"> Your total is: £<output name="result"></output></p>
</form>
```