# How to calculate automatically number of days between two dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

How to calculate number of days between two dates  automatically. When I enter the second date, the number of days will be generated automatically in the span of the code below without using any button?
I have this html code :

```html
<div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="col">
        <label for="from">fom</label>
        <input type="date" required="" class="form-control" name="from">  
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <label for="to">to</label>
        <input type="date" required="" class="form-control" name="to">
    </div>
    <span>I want to get the difference in days between two this dates here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run function on <input> change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806948/javascript-run-function-on-input-change-no-jquery)

Comment: No, does not help